# Mysql varchar Column Size impact on performance?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in Mysql 5.7, which is large and is growing rapidly, currently it is 55 million rows.

There is a column in it called `reference_number`, it is a `varchar(255)`, but generally it has only max 20-25 char long string in it, it is indexed column. Now doing a query on it works pretty good with indexing in place.

Now question I really have is, will changing the column size to `varchar(25)` give me any significant improvement in query performance, if not query does this change going to yield me any other benefits in long run?

Comment: if you are using utf8mb4 collation then you'll see performance gain in read queries and index on utf8mb4 supports Up to the first 191 characters.
https://serversforhackers.com/c/mysql-utf8-and-indexing

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/mysql-varchar-length-and-performance

Comment: Aspects of these links are a little out of date

Comment: So it looks like (after reading those articles shared above), There isn't going to be much of a difference as I am using Innodb and utf8_general_ci charset